# Installaling app on Nexus 5 Failed with INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, nexus-5

I am Android novice and I had an app on my Nexus 5 (not rooted) and I uninstalled it by going to Settings->Apps->MyApp->Uninstall.  That completed successfully.

Then I wanted to install same app .apk, so I did it from adb by issuing
adb C:\MyDir\MyApp.apk and I got the error:

C:\MyDir>adb install MyApp.apk
4542 KB/s (2795833 bytes in 0.601s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/MyApp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

I goggled a bit and everyone suggests that the app did not uninstall properly but I can not go back to Settings->Apps->MyApp since MyApp is not showing there any more.  However, I tried issuing adb uninstall but I get failure DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR.  I guess I get this error because MyApp is already uninstalled.

Much appreciated,

Comment: You can try to sign your app with a different version number.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you unisnstall a debuged app with the phone the package stills on the same preferences place (that's just an android bug). Yeah, you havent the app but the phone thinks you still having it.

Then, just uninstall this package from that place:

1.- go to cmd

2.- execute "dir c:\your_folder_to_sdk\platform-tools"

3.- execute "adb uninstall your.app.package"

note: If you have your path to adb alredy installed on your windows/mac system, the step 2 is not necesary